# Role-dependent user login

Tags: reactjs, react-native

From the API server, I receive the role information after logging in.

If it is a user with management rights, it should load a different screen after logging in.

App.js

This must be loaded for the regular user

```
AppTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Settings: {screen: SettingsScreen},
  Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
  Board: {screen: BoardScreen},
})
```

And that's for the managing person

```
AppTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Settings: {screen: SettingsScreen},
  Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
  Board: {screen: BoardScreen},
  Configuration: {screen: ConfigurationScreen},
})
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: What did you mean by "When logging in to Json" ? What did you tried ?

Comment: @estus Setting the Navigation structure is in the App.js file. How can this depend on the login status as this file will be loaded first in the application?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. But the question should contain clear problem statement and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @estus Depending on who logs in I want to load another TabNavigator which is in the App.js file. Briefly

Answer (score 1):

If it is just two types of users, it can be easily done with a conditional render.

```
// imports

const RegularUserNavigation = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Settings: {screen: SettingsScreen},
  Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
  Board: {screen: BoardScreen},
});
const ManagementUserNavigation = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Settings: {screen: SettingsScreen},
  Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
  Board: {screen: BoardScreen},
  Configuration: {screen: ConfigurationScreen},
});

export default class YourScreen extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  state = {
    // I'm assuming once you sign in,
    // these state variables are changed inside your login function
    signedIn: false,
    userRole: null,
  }

  renderManagementUserNavigation = () => {
    return (<ManagementUserNavigation />);
  }

  renderRegularUserNavigation = () => {
    return (<RegularUserNavigation />);
  }

  renderSignInContent = () => {
    // render the sign in contents here
  }

  render() {
    const {signedIn, userRole} = this.state;
    let result = null;

    if (signedIn) {
      result = userRole === 'regular' ?
        this.renderRegularUserNavigation() :
        this.renderManagementUserNavigation();
    } else {
      result = this.renderSignInContent();
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

**NOTE** - Explicitly rendering more than one Navigation is not recommended. See [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/common-mistakes.html#explicitly-rendering-more-than-one-navigator). But we have to use something like this to conditionally render the navigations.